# To process uploaded file for certain content type, how to?

Tags: 6, hooks

For example:

- A new content type `Photo` is created
- The optional core module `Upload` is enabled
- Such that users can upload JPEG files

How can I:

- In view mode of a `Photo` node, show a small "View EXIF" button next to the `Photo`
- When the user click the "View EXIF" button, my module show some EXIF info about that photo

i.e.:

- add a button only for a particular content type (`Photo` in this example)
- trigger a hook to process a uploaded file (a JPEG file in this example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Exif](http://drupal.org/project/exif) module to grab your exif data from the uploaded image:

Use some simple theming (eg: create node-photo.tpl.php if you are using d6 and content type is called 'photo') - there do some simple jquery show / hide type stuff with a div wrapped around your exif data.